# Angular JSON vs JSONP $promise

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

if i make this JSON call from my controller.js:

```
$scope.userInvestors = userInvestors.query({UserID:$scope.user.uid}, 
  function(userInvestors) {
    console.log("yep yer here");
}
```

with this $resource:

```
factory('userInvestors', function($resource){
  return $resource('http://wherevertheserveris/Rest/userInvestors.php', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
  });
})
```

then the console is updated as expected with: yep yer here

however if I change the request to a JSONP request:

```
$scope.userInvestors = userInvestors.query({UserID:$scope.user.uid, 
  callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}, function(userInvestors) {
    console.log("but are you here?");
}
```

and the resource:

```
factory('userInvestors', function($resource){
  return $resource('http://wherevertheserveris/Rest/userInvestors.php', {}, {
    query: {method:'JSONP', params:{}, isArray:true}

  });
})
```

nothing is printed to the console even though I know the call was completed and the data retrieved?

how do I get my JSONP log statement to print?

### ANSWER:

thanks to both answers below: I needed to properly format the return response from the API.

In the case of NULL I was returning via PHP: `print $callback."null";`

What I needed to return was just an empty array inside a function wrapper, or whatever other properly formatted JSONP response you find appropriate. In my case it was: `print $callback."([])";`

Comment: make sure API is returning jsonp and not json that isn't CORS enabled. If just json, can see response body but browser can't use it from different domain

Comment: Im not sure what that means. the response is JSONP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make sure that what data format is returning from back-end. JSONP response is a JSON data with a function call wrapped around it.

**My php API implementation:**

```
<?php
    $callback = isset($_GET['callback'])?$_GET['callback']:'JSON_CALLBACK';

    $array = array("name"=>"test","email"=>"test@digital.com");

    echo $callback."(".json_encode($array).")";
?>
```

Because the wrapped function call name is determined by the param 'callback', remember to assign proper name to callback param and custom method property 'callback' when you're using ngResource module.

**Angular implementation:**

```
angular.module("app",['ngResource'])
.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,userInvertors){
    $scope.jsonpTest = function(){
        $scope.result = userInvertors.query(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
})
.factory("userInvertors",function($resource){
    return $resource('http://your.domain.com/API/getUser/123',{},{
        query:{
            method:'JSONP',
            params:{callback:"JSON_CALLBACK"},
            callback:"JSON_CALLBACK"
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ngResource</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ngResource.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="button" ng-click="jsonpTest()" value="JSONP"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screen shot:**

API:

[image]

Get response:
   [image]

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: I had everything correct with the exception of No results being returned in which case I implemented the following PHP:
`print $callback."([])";`

Answer (score 1):

You should do 2 things:
1. In your JSONP `userInvestors` service spesify `callback` parameter with value of 'JSON_CALLBACK';
2. In your `userInvestors.php` script get `callback`request variable and use it's value for reply preparation:

**PHP CODE:**

```
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
$jsonStr = "...";
header("Content-type: text/javascript");

echo $callback."(".jsonStr.")";
```