# Angular js $http request get fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function PhoneInfo($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'myurl/?',
        params: { 'company': '1571', 'secret': 'complex15', 'mode': 'phoneinfo', 'outputtype': 'json' }
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $scope.PhoneState = data;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.status = status;
        alert('Error');
    });
}
```

When calling the url directly from browser, its giving Json string
but in above code, its giving error. I am very new to Angular JS. Please help, thanks

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular JSON vs JSONP $promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206817/angular-json-vs-jsonp-promise)

Comment: Angular converts the json automatically to an object when received. It issues an error if the received json is syntactically wrong.

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting to help, A Plunker would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [angularjs http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation.

Use .then() and pass success and error functions.

```
function PhoneInfo($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'myurl/?',
            params: { 'company': '1571', 'secret': 'complex15', 'mode': 'phoneinfo', 'outputtype': 'json' }
        }).then(function (response) {
            alert(response.data);
            $scope.PhoneState = response.data;
        },
        function (response) {
            $scope.status = response.status;
            alert('Error');
        });
    }
```

Comment: A little correction: *"The promise doesn't have success and error methods"*. The promises `success` and `error` still exists but they're **deprecated**. Of course, they shouldn't be used, **but** I doubt that is the cause of the *issue*.

Comment: I'm not sure but i just updated my answer.. It would be great if you (@CharlieH & @developer033) provide a link to the document contains success and error methods for http promise.

Comment: Please look inside angular code. success is implemented very well.